# Oracle jdk in development and Jrockit in production, will this leads any issue?

Tags: java

We have developed Project using Oracle(sun) Jdk1/6 and also WAR was compiled and prepared using Oracle(sun) Jdk1/6. Now, we want to setup the Production environment with JRockit to get the Performance gain of JRockit.

Will this be lead to any problem?

Comment: Most probably not, but you never know. As long as the JDK libraries you use are the same you shouldn't have any problems. From my experience changing the JVM or even the Java version is less a source for errors than changing libraries (like the XML libs) which unfortunately happens sometimes when using another JRE/JDK.

Comment: I just want to know does it affect the performance(in a good way) if we use the Jrockit in production ???

Comment: Yes, when use the JRockit performance would again.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not a good idea. I know is very rare, but u can get into JVM bug that u could have only in production system. Develepment on your machine with JDK is not a problem, but have a Test enviroment different  from Production enviroment can be unuseful.

However I build for over 4 years with JDK and deploy on Jrockit without problem.